# Laravel Auth Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel's auth class requires a database in order for it to be used right?

Does that consider database coming from the server having their own authentication process ?
Cause I want to use Laravel's Auth class methods where I can distinguish if the user is logged in or not so that I can prevent them(who have logged out) from clicking the back button.

Comment: Laravel assumes you have a table named "users" in your database.

Comment: Yes, I know that much, but can I still use it even though i didn't create any database with direct connection to my project? like for example I am accessing a database from a server

Comment: Well, as long as you have a database connection (local or remote) set up with Laravel and it has a table users it should technically work.

Comment: even though I don't use Laravel's own logging in method `Auth::attempt()` will it still work when I use `Auth::check()`?

Comment: Oh, that I don't know. Have you tried? What happened?

Comment: No I haven't I'm still confirming about the database, it's still in theory but I think I'll give it a try

Comment: @elclanrs I tried using `Auth::check()` when I successfully logged in using my server's authentication method but as I predicted it won't work cause Auth class doesn't have a connection to my server's authentication method that's why for Auth class the user is still not logged in and `Auth:check` returns `false`

Comment: @elclanrs to use the `Auth::check()` I modified the `Auth::logout()` and `Auth::login()` it's actually working, but since i don't 'actually' let laravel see my database it doesn't work since it doesn't store the values it get from the login using laravel's session class

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4 by default support two authentication driver, 'Eloquent' and 'Database', refer to the file you have in your `app\config\auth.php`, this is set to Eloquent by default.

The Eloquent ORM itself by default tied to a table in your database, though I have seen it creating tables by itself when no tables are found (maybe someone else can clarify this).

If you are not using the `Auth::attempt()` then it is of best practice to call the `Auth::login()` or `Auth::loginUsingId()` in your application. However this depends on how far you want to use your own authentication method (or how much you want to use the bundled authentication, for that matter).

Comment: I don't want to use the `Auth::login()` because the server does that function. I only want to the `Auth::check()` to check if the user is still log in instead of using sessions for the back button. But it seems that Laravel's Auth class doesn't recognize the authetication that my server sends me that's why `Auth::check()` doesn't work, is there any other way to tell the Auth class that my user is logged in without using Auth class' own login method ??

Comment: Is your server use their own table structure for storing User information? And also do you have User Eloquent model?

Comment: Yes. No, i don't manage the database, I just send the information to the server. I've been thinking of modifying the `Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php` since this is where the functions `user()`, `check()`  of Auth class can be found. So I think instead of placing my curl functions in the controller I'll place them in `Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php` then it will be the one to catch whatever the server's returning.. ?

Comment: Yeah do give that a try. Or, start as a filter. Write a filter that filters every route with a curl call to your server (assuming that is how your authentication mechanism work?)

Comment: will it be able to handle if the user clicks the back button? if I'm not mistaken I think the headers are set to `no-cached` by default so the page refreshes but the user is still logged in even though the server returns true when I log out of my page(if this makes any sense)

Comment: In my opinion (others might be able to back me up here), back is handled at the mercy of user's browser. You can't force the browser to do something according to your rules when user press back. What you can do though is to use jQuery that runs and validate the user each time a page is loaded.

Comment: `"You can't force the browser to do something according to your rules when user press back"` if that's the case, this is where I was planning to use Laravel's auth class. In the `layout.blade` I want to use `@if(Auth::check())` before displaying the contents `@else` user will be redirected, but I realize as well it's not best practice, is it?